# Multiple mysql statements on same connection

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, user-variables

I'm building a search query and was wondering if the code below would be valid. Basically I would set the @keywords variable in the first statement and then use it in the 2nd statement. It seems to be working just fine but I'm not sure if it's a good procedure. Any ideas? :)

The point would be that the query would be more complex and @keyword would show up a number of times.

```
$list_images_kw = $mysqli_link->prepare("SET @keyword=?;");
$list_images_kw->bind_param('s', $search_string);
$list_images_kw->execute();
$list_images_kw->close();                 
$list_images = $mysqli_link->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE UCASE(`images`.img_title) REGEXP @keyword" ); 
$list_images->execute();
$list_images->close();
```

Comment: Why you don't enclosing all that statements into a stored procedure ?

Comment: Yep... looks like that is the perfect solution :) Time to put the "Bang Your Head Here" sign back on the wall and learn how to create stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested I have found the series of tutorials for MySQL Stored procuders. Is realy good and very simple to learn how to create your own!

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Comment: actually the servers it will need to run on has mysql4, so back to square 1 :(